# Mapping scipy percentileofscore over a 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am attempting to take several years of data and calculate the percentile of the value of the most recent year. The array I am ultimately working with is a 3D array `arr` with shape (585, 1386, 3)=(lat, lon, year) of a value *erc*.

```
array_list = []

data = 'erc_1979.nc'
files = sorted(glob.glob('erc_*'))

for x, f in enumerate(files):
    
    nc = Dataset(data, mode = 'r')   
    erc = nc.variables['energy_release_component-g'][:]
    nc.close()
    array_list.append(erc)

arr = np.ma.concatenate(array_list, axis=0) #makes 3D array

###calculate percentiles 
def f(x):
    return percentileofscore(x, x[-1])

res = np.apply_along_axis(f, 0, arr)
```

Comment: your error means that you are supplying a keyword argument before a positional argument i.e. `*args` should go before `**kwargs`. add the parameter name that you are passing the `arr` variable to i.e. `arr_per = np.apply_along_axis(stats.percentileofscore(), axis=2, arr=arr)`

Comment: also, when you pass a function to another function, don't include the parentheses or you are passing the result of the function, not the function itself. do `arr_per = np.apply_along_axis(stats.percentileofscore, axis=2, arr=arr)`

Comment: This fixes the first error, but I still have the issue of the args for percentileofscore... the next error is TypeError: percentileofscore() missing 1 required positional argument: 'score'. The part I'm confused on is how to code that as the last element of that slice...

Comment: not 100% sure what you're trying to do from your question - could you post a sample input and expected output? doesn't have to be the full array, just a subset

Comment: Are you trying to get the percentile of the last year over the previous years? Or to take only the last year's values and normalize?

Comment: things that need clarifying: (1) does your array contain (a) 585 * 1386 values with latitude in the first slice of the 3rd dimension, longitude in the 2nd and year in the 3rd OR (b) 585 * 1386 * 3 values of some other quantity where the first dimension represents the latitude, the second represents the longitude and the third represents the year i.e. you have 3 years of data. (2) if (b) then do you want to find the percentile of the value out of the values in the final year (3rd slice) out of just the values in that year i.e. just the last slice, or from all years i.e. all 3 slices?

Comment: Sorry... trying to work up an example that makes sense. YES, I have three years of data, but the data I have is for the day in question, so its 585*1386*3 and I want to find the percentile of the value in the final year, compared to all three years... ...ultimately wanting an array with the same first two dimensions where each element equals the percentile of the last element along the third axis of the 3D array (day (of the year) is the third axis).

Comment: slices would look something like `p1 = percentileofscore(arr[i,j,:], arr[i,j,-1], kind='rank')` for each `i` and `j` (lat and lon). Desired output of 585*1386 full of percentiles on a given day.

Comment: ok then i think @Aaron Keesing's answer below looks right

Comment: There is a problem with the function, I believe... the code runs without an error but the output array is all the same values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, for each (lat, long) combination you want the percentile of the last year's value compared to all years' values? So you can do something like this:

```py
def f(x):
    return stats.percentileofscore(x, x[-1])

res = np.apply_along_axis(f, 2, arr)
```

Comment: Actually, I was wrong... for some reason it is outputting `res` as an array with the correct dimensions but all of the elements are the same. I'm still trying to figure out why... there's nothing wrong with the input array

Comment: maybe you can post a small slice of your array in the question e.g. `arr[:5, :4, :]`, with expected outputs?

Comment: lets say I have `a=np.shape((3,3,3))`, I can manually make slices that would look something like a[0,0,:], a[0,1,:], a[0,2,:], a[1,0,:], etc. If I added all these to a list as 1D arrays, I can use a for loop: `for x in list: p1 = percentileofscore(x, x[-1])`. I would want an output of `res = ([p1,p2,p3],[p4,p5,p6],[p7,p8,p9])`. This gives me a variety of values for res. Some how with the application of np.apply_along_axis the function isnt being updated

Comment: The code I gave should do exactly that. Without knowing some of your input data and what the actual and expected results are, I can't help you.

Comment: The array I'm using has a mask, so it looks rather odd...digging into things a little bit, there might be something wrong with how I'm concatenating the yearly arrays together; using day as an integer defined above, I have `erc = nc.variables['energy_release_component-g'][day,:,:]` followed with `array_list.append(erc)` and then `arr = np.dstack(array_list)` My output from the slice arr[200:205,500:505,:] is just [[32676,32676,32676]...all the same value. Might have something to do with the mask?

Comment: I suggest you edit your question with a fuller description of your input data type, shape, mask, etc. and what the array actually looks like. Look at [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can actually figure out what's going on.

Comment: I am a dumb ass. I made a computational error earlier on in the code; I've posted the working script. Thanks for all your patience and help, sorry to waste more of your time

Comment: If this answer worked for you then could you please mark it as correct so it's no longer in the 'unanswered questions' list?